# Can I use Flysystem with backup_migrate?

Tags: 8, backups

I would like to use Backup & Migrate for my Drupal 8 site. 
Is there a way to use Flysystem for backups?
Should I install S3FS?

I have Flysystem configured to handle all of my files and images to be saved and served from an S3 bucket. I do not see any capability to add an S3 bucket to Backup and Migrate.

I did install and enable S3FS but do not see the configuration for backup files only.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title's question: No, because the files are stored in your S3 bucket. You don't need to backup these files because Drupal reads them from your S3 bucket's server. Since your files are not stored locally, you don't need to migrate them, ever.

If you're paranoid about losing your S3 files, have a read, [Backup strategies for AWS S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832860/backup-strategies-for-aws-s3-bucket).